# mvc5 fill List<> before using in HTML

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, list, foreach

I am using MVC 5 and Visual Studio 2013.

In my HTML I am using

> @model namespace.Models.UserViewModel

and my UserViewModel  is a model class defined like this.

[image]

I have also my `Gender` class defined like this, where I fill my `SexList` with `Male` and `Female` genders.

[image]

What I want to do is to add a radio button for each option in my list.

So in my HTML I add

[image]

But in runtime have an error saying

> Model.SexList is empty.

My question is how can I fill my list before using it?

Comment: Pro tip: You can remove your `set` declaration since the property should be immutable.

Comment: You need to include your code in the question, not images of it. And your `RadioButtonFor()` makes no sense - look at the html your generating, in particular the `value` attribute

Answer (score 1):

The question you posted itself is wrong.

The code where you do

```
List<Gender> lista = null;
lista.Add(new Gender { ID =1, Type = "Male"}); 
// ^^ this line gives you run time error as object does not have a instance.
```

You need to create an instance of the object and then add the items into it

```
 List<Gender> lista = new List<Gender>();
```

With this change your code is good to exhibit the desired behavior unless you have changed the contents of the `SexList` else where before the for loop, Which you have not posted in your question.

Comment: thanks... so, my question would be, where may I put the contents of the SexList in order to have it filled when I reach the loop?

Comment: Rajshekar.. I am still missing something.. I replaced 
List<Gender> lista = null;
with
List<Gender> lista = new List<Gender>();
But still Model.SexList is empty... when I load the HTML...

Comment: @Diego that is not possible brother. Are you sure that the `SexList` property is not modified anywhere in the before the loop?

Answer (score 0):

For what you have posted it seems like you have forgot to instantiate your list.

You should have a `lista = new List<Gender>()`, as you haven´t instantiate it you should be getting exception trying to add new elements to the list.

Other alternative you could to is to place to SexList initialization in the class constructor:

```
public UserViewModel() 
{
   SexList = new List<Gender>();
   SexList.Add...
}
```

Or make it (the SexyList property) static already initializing it.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill SexList in the User object like below

```
foreach (var user in users)
        {
            user.SexList=new SexList(){}
        }
```